Как в телеграм боте на aiogram 3.15 обработать mediagroup?
День добрый. Делаю бота, который обрабатывал бы сообщения в телеграм канале. Прочел, что фото, текст и видео можно обработать магическим фильтром, т.е.
@main_router.channel_post(F.photo)
#некоторые действия...
@main_router.channel_post(F.video)
#некоторые действия...
@main_router.channel_post(F.audio)
#некоторые действия...

Но как быть с медиагруппой? Как сделать обработку на медиагруппу, чтобы в дальнейшем скачать файлы из сообщения и дальше с ними шаманить?
